# Why is it beneficial to make async REST services?

Tags: spring, multithreading

Spring allows a method annotated with `@RequestMapping` to return a variety of objects, including a `CompletableFuture` or a `Future`. This allows me to spawn off an async method and let spring return the value whenever it is ready. What I am not sure I am understanding is if there are any benefits to this. For instance:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/user/{userId}")
    public CompletableFuture<User> getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
              () -> this.dataAccess.getUser(userId));
}
```

In this case, even though the actual computation is happening in the background, the connection will still not close and the request thread will still be active till it is done. How is it better than say:

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{userId}")
public User getUser(@PathVariableS("userId") String userId) {
    return this.dataAccess.getUser(userId);
}
```

From first glances, this seems to be a better approach as there is no overhead with an additional thread and a watcher that looks for completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes advantage of Servlet 3 asynchronous request processing, using `request.startAsync()` method. Read [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3)

> To achieve this, a Servlet 3 web application can call request.startAsync() and use the returned AsyncContext to continue to write to the response from some other separate thread. At the same time from a client's perspective the request still looks like any other HTTP request-response interaction. It just takes longer to complete. The following is the sequence of events: